# Customize ESRI Template Picker Widget

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the template picker from the ESRI JS API.  As far as I see it, the look and feel of the picker, cannot be customized very much at all.  The rows and columns can be controlled, and in the API reference it mentions a style parameter, which does not seem to be able to do very much.  What i would like to do, is to display the features in the Template picker in more of a list style.[image: Default template View]  As you see in the first image (to the right), the patch is shown on the top of the image with the description below that.  This style takes up a lot of real estate on the webpage.  I would prefer to horizontally align the patch and the description, like you would see in a typical legend.  is this possible, or does anyone know of another method to use a template picker like menu to activate the Editor in JS?

Comment: Any update on it? I am having same issue, and want to customize the template picker to have simple buttons instead of generate template based on the feature layer.

Comment: Sorry Jamil - I am unaware of any edits or updates to this widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the text by the side of the symbol

I have modified style in the sample code from esri https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/ed_template_picker.html

You can find the updated code at http://jsfiddle.net/DineshAtPowel/025kv88y/1/

Comment: This look pretty cool - thanks for sticking with it and sharing an answer!